# Using Title Case on Everything Except Last 2 Characters

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have addresses in my attribute table that I converted to title case from upper case.

> Example: 123 FAKEVILLE ST NW to 123 Fakeville St Nw

How can I make it so that the last 2 characters in all of the addresses in the Address column are in uppercase? In the example above, I need **Nw** in uppercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will convert ALL last 2 characters to uppercase, even if these characters are not directions (Nw, Sw,...) :

```
concat( 
  substr( title( "fieldname"), 1, length( "fieldname")-2), 
  upper(substr("fieldname", length( "fieldname")-1, 2))
)
```